# Arrange words according to their length

Tags: java

INPUT: this is my string

OUTPUT: is my this string

I have to arrange words in a sentence according to their length and if two words have the same length then print them alphabetically (the first priority is length).

My incorrect code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class accordingtolength
   {
       void main()
       {
           String result="";
           Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter the String");
           String str=sc.nextLine();
           String arr[]=str.split(" ");
           int l=arr.length;
           for(int i=0;i<l-1;i++)
           {
               String temp=arr[i]+" ";
               String temp1=arr[i+1]+" ";
               int a=temp.length();
               int b=temp1.length();
               if(a==b)
               {
                   int c=temp.compareTo(temp1);
                   if(c>0)
                   result=temp1.concat(temp);
                   else
                   result=temp.concat(temp1);
                }
                else if(a>b)
                result=temp1.concat(temp);
                else
                result=temp.concat(temp1);
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
```

I know my code is incorrect so there is no need to attach the output.

Please help.

Comment: sort the string array first. then, join the strings.

Comment: Do you mean alphabetically? But my first priority is length.

Comment: nope. Yours is similar to bubble sort but with 1 loop instead of 2, which won't sort it properly.

Comment: Sir, I didn't get it, I guess that will sort it in alphabetical order?

Comment: What I mean is, it'll require 2 for-loop for sorting. But you only have 1. Your `if` conditions should come within the 2nd for-loop.

Comment: **I know my code is incorrect so there is no need to attach the output.** Wrong. We always ask you to provide a [mcve] and that includes the **actual** output. Dont expect people to **run** your code to figure what comes out of it. And then: remember that you write code for HUMAN readers. Just FORGET about using useless 1 char variable names. Practice to use variable names that are MEANINGFUL to human readers. And also put braces around all your blocks, and to properly indent your code. All these things make it sooo much harder to read your input as it ought to be.

Comment: So, the real answer is: step back. Write down a small example, and then try to sort it manually, in your head. Try to write down the steps that you have to do. Maybe read up about the sorting ALGORITHM you want to use. THINK it through, understand how it is supposed to work. Then compare that with your implementation. And when you dont understand what your code is doing: add more print statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you were looking for.  Using minimal external classes, this simply sorts the array of words in ascending order based on their length first and then alphabetically if those lengths are equal It uses a `variant` of what is known as a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). It is a basic sort and quite often used as an introduction to sorting. But it is not very efficient.

- read in the string and split based on spaces (I modified your regex to allow 1 or more spaces).
- then use nested loops to iterate thru the list, comparing lengths.
- if the word indexed by the `outer` loop (`i`) is longer than the word indexed by the `inner` loop (`j`), swap the words.
- else if equal length compare words to each other and sort alphabetically (the String class implements the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface).
- when both loops are finished, the array will be sorted in
- then you can just iterate over the result building a string of words separated by spaces.

```
public class AccordingToLength {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the String:");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        
        String arr[] = str.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
            int outer = arr[i].length();
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                int inner = arr[j].length();
                if (outer > inner || outer == inner && arr[i].compareTo(arr[j]) > 0) {
                    String temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                    outer = inner; // outer has new length (what was just swapped)
                }
            }
        }
        
        String result = "";
        for (String word : arr) {
            result += word + " ";
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

for input = `"if a day now any easy when new test is done do den deed none";` this prints

```
a do if is any day den new now deed done easy none test when
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem. The two most convenient ways are.

1. If you are allowed to use streams and comparator, then you can achieve it in a single line.

   ```
   Arrays.stream(arr)
          .sorted(Comparator
                          .comparing(String::length)
                          .thenComparing(Function.identity()))
          .forEach(System.out::println);
   ```
2. Using Arrays.sort() to sort the actual array elements.

   ```
   Arrays.sort(arr, (o1, o2) -> {
        if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o2.length() > o1.length()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
   ```
3. If you don't want to use java provided APIs and data structures, you can implement a different version of bubble sort.

   ```
    boolean isSwapped;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        isSwapped = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j].length() > arr[j + 1].length()
                    || arr[j].length() == arr[j + 1].length() && arr[j].compareTo(arr[j + 1]) > 0) {
                swap(arr, j, j + 1);
                isSwapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isSwapped)
            break;
    }
   ```

Comment: Maybe, I am allowed to use it but I haven't heard about this thing before.

Comment: Streams were introduced in java 8. You can learn about them it will help you.

Comment: Can you write or give an idea of writing the custom code (not involving external classes and not many methods)? I also did +1

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve a problem, and using stream is the easiest way to achieve it in java. However, if you don't want to use this approach, you can always create a frequency map with lengths as key and then merge the value. You can also use Arrays.sort if you want to sort the actual array. I will add this approach to the answer.

Comment: Please: when people implement a sorting algorithm themselves, they do that because that is part of their education. Their assignment is: IMPLEMENT SORTING YOURSELF, not: use some sorting coming out of libraries. So please please please: if you answer such requests, then heck, take the time to figure what is wrong in their implementation, instead of just going "here is a detour that avoids you fixing your not-working code"

Comment: *and using stream is the easiest way to achieve it in java.* is pure opinion, and a lot of people would disagree. Please be much more careful about stating YOUR OPINION as if it were fact to people who are newbies to the language.

Comment: Got what you are trying to say, will add a solution as well.